# Google sign in for flutter web - Request offline access

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am using google_sign_in_web 0.10.2 https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web and following the posted [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/example/lib/main.dart)

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
            _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
          setState(() {
            _currentUser = account;
          });
          if (_currentUser != null) {
            _handleGetContact(_currentUser!);
          }
        });
        _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
      }
```

I can't find a way to set the `access_type` to `offline`.

Is this set by default by the library? Else how?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not know this specific library. But Google Sign-In usually sets a local token that allows signing it even if offline. This token becomes invalid after a certain amount of time. And the user has to sign-in online again.

Comment: @Dabbel so is the access token that I get in exchange for my authorization code valid for offline access, even if I have not set offline access explicitly? I suppose there must be a difference

Comment: As far as I know it makes no difference to the App. For example, if you use Firebase and set a rule that a user has to be logged in, the App will still be able to access the Firebase offline / cached data.

Comment: @Dabbel that answer does not resolve my problem, it only provides an alternative to refresh the credentials, I need the refresh_token explicitly, because i have to send it to the backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is currently not possible: the source code of this library explicitly mentions it:

```
    // On Android, there isn't an API for refreshing the idToken, so re-use
    // the one we obtained on login.
    response.idToken ??= _idToken;
```

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/lib/google_sign_in.dart#L102

There are also open issues and an open pull request which address this issue:

- https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/3356 is a PR aiming to fix this
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45847 is an issue describing this problem.
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15796 another issue

**But it is coming!**

It looks like very recently (5 days ago) a new parameter `forceCodeForRefreshToken`  has been merged into the development version: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/6130 and will be coming into 6.1.0 (not released yet).